# Mockserver -Replay

Tags: mocking, wiremock

I am using JamesDBloom Mockserver. I looking at enabling a standalone instance which can be used by developers to test the external calls. This requires feature of being able to record and replay without any deployment - code changes. While I was able to record the request , response  I am not able to figure out a way of indicating to the mockserver to use request response as recorded without - java or javascript change. Has anybody tried this? In case of wiremock, i was able to do this by copying the request response in mappings.

Comment: I could do this finally by using a tool like soap ui and doing a put operation at /expectations with the expectation stubbing in JS as specified in the documentation. However since this is going to be inmemory ,we will need to run  a soap ui testsuite on every restart of mockserver.

Answer (score 0):

I could do this finally by using a tool like soap ui and doing a put operation at /expectations with the expectation stubbing in JS as specified in the documentation. However since this is going to be inmemory ,we will need to run a soap ui testsuite on every restart of mockserver.